# Color calibration on Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, windows, colors, css

I noticed that colours on Ubuntu look different than on Windows, on the same laptop. The problem is that when I use Photoshop in Virtualbox and I make a solid colour image in one colour, and when I view it on a host OS (Ubuntu), the colour looks different. I work as a web designer, and this bugs me, because stuff doesn't look the same.

Let me show it to you.

[image]

This is part of my website as viewed in Virtualbox Windows. You can notice that all of the green lines look the same. Top line is defined in CSS, and the shape below it is a PNG image. Colours are the same.

Now, lets see how that looks in Ubuntu.

[image]

The top line (CSS defined) is the same, but the image below changes its colour to a more vivid tone.

The screen is not the problem since this doesn't happen in Virtualbox on Windows, only on Ubuntu (host OS).

Is there any way to calibrate colours on Ubuntu, like it's possible on Windows?

I tried the Colours app in System settings, but the Calibrate button is greyed out, I can't click on it, and other options do not provide any calibration.

Since it's a laptop I can't do it manually, so it has to be done via software. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: I don't think it's a calibration problem, otherwise also on the second image you would have the same colour on the two lines (different than on 
Windows, but the same), while you have two different colours. I think it's a problem of colour profiles. What colour profile do you use for your png?

Comment: BTW it is possibile and rather easy to calibrate your monitor, if you have a calibre. I use [ColorHUG](http://www.hughski.com/), it's a very nice and reliable piece of open hardware :)

Comment: You are right, I didn't think of that. The colour profile is the default one, the one that came with Ubuntu when I installed it. You can see it here: http://i.imgur.com/0TAOHsM.png

Comment: I am not a expert in Ubuntu (yet ahah) so pardon me if I missed something.  Please tell me how to see/find the stuff that might help you :D

Comment: I read a bit, the best thing is to remove the embedded color profile from your png. I'm not sure how to do that with Photoshop, though...

Comment: With a bit help of Google I found the way. When creating a new image in Photoshop you need to set it to "dont color manage this document". I replaced all my images and now it works. Thanks A LOT, you were right :D

Comment: Great! :) Should I write an answer then?

Comment: Please do. 
Answer is to open (in Photoshop) every PNG image (that causes problems) and then copy it (CTRL+A -> CTRL+C).
Then create new image in Photoshop (CTRL+N), and in settings of new image under Advance tab change Color profile from "sRGB ..." to "dont color manage this document".

Now my PNG images look the same on Ubuntu and Windows :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the embedded Color Profile, not the calibration of the monitor (otherwise the second image would show a uniform green, although different from the first one).

In order to avoid these problems, it is a good practice to produce pictures without an embedded color profile, so that then web browsers will use their own color profiles to show them, and this will embed them better in CSS.